# Getting started with unit testing for c++ in eclipse on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, eclipse, unit-testing, ubuntu

I've recently switched to an Ubuntu os where I'm working on an important c++ project. I am using eclipse as an IDE and I was wandering what is the best way to do unit testing considering I've never done any unit testing. 
Links for tutorials would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I used google test for unit testing my project which is C++ based. It is easy to set up and use. Please check the below link.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/811934/Cplusplus-unit-test-start-guide-how-to-set-up-Goog